# Create tableHeaderView that always fills the frame of the visible table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I need to implement the ability to display a label perfectly centered on screen with nothing else visible, but this needs to be done in a `UITableView`. The setup is a `UISpiltViewController` that has a `UITableViewController` for the detail view controller, and when no item is selected on the left I want to display a message stating that on the right, and when the user selects an item that label should instantly disappear and reveal the table. (Just like the Mail app.)

I already have this set up and it's working ok, but for some reason it's not always staying centered on screen, and it isn't a very good solution - there are some minor oddities for example you can partially see the top of the table while the rotation is occurring. I am just creating a `UILabel`, setting its `frame` to fill the visible area, then setting the table's `tableHeaderView` to that label, and finally disabling the ability to scroll the table. And upon rotation, the `frame` has to be updated to fill the visible area again. That's where the oddities occur, because it's not updating until after the rotation completes.

My question is, what is a better approach to implement this behavior? Is there some way I can prevent having to update the frame after rotation, would it be possible to use Auto Layout for the `tableHeaderView`?

```
//Setting the tableHeaderView
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.label;

//Creating the UILabel
- (UILabel *)label {
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width,
                                                                         self.tableView.bounds.size.height
                                                                         - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
                                                                         - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height
                                                                         - MIN([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                                                               [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width))];
    _label.text = @"Nothing Selected";
    _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _label.backgroundColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor;
    return _label;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if (_label) {
        _label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width,
                                                    self.tableView.bounds.size.height
                                                    - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
                                                    - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height
                                                    - MIN([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                                          [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width));

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Cabus, the solution is to set the `autoresizingMask` of the label to `UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight`. That way, the label will always fit its parent. This can be done while using the label for the `tableHeaderView`, and there's no longer a need for detecting orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

Is your detail controller a UITableViewController? If so, that makes things harder since any subviews you add (your label) become part of the table. It would be easier if you use a UIViewController, and alternately hide the label or table view when you need to. The label can be any size, and use centerX and centerY constraints to keep it centered. If you do it that way, you won't have to do anything on rotation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that specifically. Yes it is a `UITableViewController`, and I would definitely prefer to keep it that way. :)

Comment: @Joey, Why? I don't understand why so many people stick with UITableViewController. It doesn't give you much that you can't do easily with a UIViewController, and it makes things like what you're trying to do more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the label as the headerView of your `UITableView`.

You can simply add the label to `self.view`. Even if you are running inside a `UITableViewController`, each `UIViewController` always has a view property.

Add the label to self.view and toggle the visibility of the label and the tableView as needed.
This is much easier, than trying to fiddle the label in the tableview - hierarchy ;)

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @rdelmar, the UITableViewController indeed does not have a separate view which contains the tableview, but rather uses the tableview as it's view directly. -.-

Sorry. I did assume the two views were separated.

All I can say is follow @rdelmar s advice, and stop using UITableViewController. It forces you to do things the default way, and if you want to customized it you WILL have a bad time :(

**EDIT 2**

Ok so you have 2 options:

1) Do the following:

```
[_label setAutoResizingMask:(UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight)];
```

in your label getter. That way, you don't have to care about screen rotation anymore. The label will always fit its parents bounds.

2) Use UIViewController and treat the label as a sibling of the tableView. <- Better approach but requires more refactoring from your current state.

Comment: That does work, but still suffers from the same problems. You can see the rest of the table underneath this view (and now to the right of it) upon rotating on iPad. Again because it doesn't update the frame until rotation is finished. But maybe with this solution I can use auto layout?

Comment: This is incorrect. The view of a UIViewController is the table view. There is no other view to add the label to (both self.view and self.tableView point to the table view).

Comment: @rdelmar They are indeed the same view, but you can still add it to the view (or tableView) and it does appear overtop the table. I tried adding auto layout constraints to this, but the `tableView.frame.size.width` is 0, so it ends up the intrinsic content size - not filling the tableView visible area. Hmm

Comment: @Joey, maybe I should have been more precise in my wording. The implication of this answer is that you can add it to some view (that's not the table) and toggle the visibility, but that's not possible with a UITableViewController. This is just what I said you should do, but it can only be done if you use a UIViewController.

Comment: @rdelmar If we're talking about the same thing, it works just fine. `[self.view addSubview:self.label];` (recognizing `view == tableView`). This causes the label to be rendered overtop the table with origin at 0,0. I just need to find a way to ensure its frame always fills the visible area even during rotation.

Comment: You can set the autoresizingMask of you label to (UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight). That way, the label will always fit its parent.

Comment: BUT: You should be aware that adding the label directly to the tableView is not very reliable. You can't be sure that the tableview won't reorder it's subviews internally, and you label gets pushed behind other views.

Comment: @Cabus Thanks! That's working. With that set it actually instantly resizes as soon as the rotation begins so when it shrinks see part of the table underneath it. That transition can't be animated, could it? It's just a minor concern though. This may address the biggest concern which is the label not centering properly. Thanks for the warning, do we know what would cause such a reorder?

Comment: My guess would be cell insertions and deletions, as well as [reloadData]. The problem is that it might work that way in this release of iOS, but you don't have control over how the UITableView handles subviews internally, so the behavior might break in future releases. :/

Comment: Aw ha! I figured out I can use the `tableHeaderView` (instead of adding it as a subview) along with the `autoresizingMask` to get the best of both worlds. I no longer have to change the frame size upon rotation. And this way it's magically not showing any table content underneath it on rotation! Beautiful, it's addressed all my problems.